# String-formatting and printing functions

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, formatting, boost

As a small exercise I have written some string formatting and printing functions in C++11. I would like a bit of code review, not so much on the merits of using this over something like `std::stringstream` or `boost::format`, but simply whether or not my implementation makes sense. I realize that simply performing string replacements isn't that robust and a more sophisticated version would actually parse the format string. I especially would like to know if my use of things like rvalue references, `std::forward`, `std::move` and variadic templates are correct, as these are the main features I was focusing on in this exercise.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdio>

namespace detail
{
    template <unsigned N, class T>
    void format_impl(std::string& str, T&& item)
    {
        char find[8];
        snprintf(find, 8, "{%d}", N);
        auto replace = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(std::forward<T>(item));
        boost::replace_all(str, find, replace);
    }

    template <unsigned N, class Head, class... Tail>
    void format_impl(std::string& str, Head&& head, Tail&&... tail)
    {
        detail::format_impl<N>(str, std::forward<Head>(head));
        detail::format_impl<N+1>(str, std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
    }
}

template <class... Args>
std::string format(const std::string& fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    std::string temp = fmt;
    detail::format_impl<0>(temp, std::forward<Args>(args)...);   
    return temp;
}

template <class... Args>
std::string format(std::string&& fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    std::string temp = std::move(fmt);
    detail::format_impl<0>(temp, std::forward<Args>(args)...);   
    return temp;
}

template <class... Args>
void print(const std::string& fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << format(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <class... Args>
void print(std::string&& fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << format(std::forward<std::string>(fmt), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    print("Hello, {0}! The answer is {1}.\n", "World", 42);
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you have overloads for `const T&` and `T&&` all over the place? `T&&` implicitly allows `T&` and `const T&` due to reference collapsing.

Comment: @Jefffrey http://rextester.com/CYOEYT58903

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention, the simple replacing is susceptible to problems if a replacement string includes a format specifier. But setting that aside, there are still a few things I would rather do differently.

**Document**. You should be sure to document your formatting language in comments; without reading the function, or the example in `main`, it's impossible to know that the formatting language uses curly braces around indices starting at zero, whether you can repeat or skip indices, or what happens if you provide an out-of-bounds index.

**Avoid C functions?** This may be personal style, but I would prefer to avoid `snprintf` in `format_impl`. I would instead probably use something like `"{" + std::to_string(N) + "}"`. The resulting local could then be marked `const`, or the expression could go directly in the call to `boost::replace_all`.

**Remove redundancy**. Jeffrey's comment about `std::string&` and `std::string&&` overloads is half right. It should be relatively rare that you need to provide both overloads. In places that are doing template type deduction on parameter `T`, `T&&` can be deduced as either type. Here there is no deduction so that cannot happen. (That's the part of the comment that was half wrong - it didn't apply here.)

Instead we have to look at how `fmt` is being used. In `format(const std::string&, ...)` this immediately makes a mutable copy called `temp`. In `format(std::string&&, ...)`, this moves the local to another mutable copy called `temp`. From there, both functions are identical. I assert that there should only be one function here.

What function? Well, you want to modify the parameter, so it needs to be mutable. If the parameter is not mutable, you'll have to make a copy. So that rules out a `const std::string&`. And as your example shows, you can't always convert to a `std::string&&`. So what's the right option? Plan vanilla `std::string`. If you call it with a `const`, the caller makes a copy; the function receives a copy that it is free to mutate. If you call it with an rvalue, the caller moves it and the function receives a copy that it is free to mutate. So the result?

```
template <class... Args>
std::string format(std::string fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    detail::format_impl<0>(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);   
    return fmt;
}
```

The same argument applies to `print` very similarly. The only question is if you'll want to explicitly mark the string it passes to format with a `std::move`, or trust your compiler to figure it out. (In this case it's simple enough I'd probably leave it out. But it does serve as implicit documentation to a future reader, so I'll show it here.)

```
template <class... Args>
void print(std::string fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << format(std::move(fmt), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

**Brush up on r-value references**: Note that your implementation of `print(std::string&& fmt, ...)` was incorrect. In particular, one of the two uses of `std::forward` is misleading. Per Scott Meyers, it's useful to think of `std::forward` as a “conditional” `std::move`. It's useful in conjunction with the deduced `T&&` parameters, which he calls “universal references.” You use this correctly in the code phrase `std::forward<Args>(args)...`, which moves each movable sub-`args`, determined by the type of the corresponding `Args`, as deduced from the call site.

However the similar looking phrase `std::forward<std::string>(fmt)` is not conditional at all. It will never move `fmt`, as it is always casting `fmt` to an lvalue type. If you were to implement this function (which I recommended against in the previous point), you would want `std::forward<std::string&&>(fmt)` which is really just a long and hard to read way of writing `std::move(fmt)`. This is correct because `print`'s `fmt` is an l-value that was moved in, and now you want to move it onward.

**The upshot** This was a good exercise that ended up focusing a lot on `std::move`, `std::forward`, and r-value references in general. There don't appear to have been any functionality problems in your implementation, although it's always good to make sure with more than one test case. If you expand on this function's robustness and capability set (say fixing the limitations from the `replace_all` approach, or adding a way to escape braced indices so that they aren't substituted) that could make another interesting review. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the review! It seems like in the case of `print` pass-by-value is not going to be the most optimal in all scenarios. In the case of passing a `std::string` lvalue for `fmt` you will wind up performing a copy *and* a move. If performance in this case was critical, would it not be best to have a `print(const string&, ...)` and a `print(string&&, ...)`? That way you will only perform a move in the case of rvalue and only a copy in the case of lvalue.

Comment: Also, in the case of `format`, I can see why pass-by-value is preferable. However, I wonder if you have any opinions on allowing implementation details like this to dictate the function's interface.

Comment: @Chris_F For caller to `print` to `format`, in my answer there's either a copy or a move, followed by a move. Your proposal could turn copy+move into ref+copy, and wouldn't change move+move. Saving a single (and likely inlined) move seems like tiny savings, but profile it to be certain. As far as interfaces go, despite the two prototypes there's only one meaningful interface to learn, so it's only the implementation savings that's important. (As a general guideline, though, prefer the correct and readable interface unless you're dealing with a true bottleneck.)