# Simple parsing for string formatting

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, formatting, boost

Recently I submitted some string formatting and printing code ([found here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56067/did-i-implement-my-string-formatting-code-correctly)) that I wrote as an small exercise. It was implemented naively using string replacement. This time around I wanted to actually parse the format string. This is the first time I've ever attempted to write code which does any type of parsing. I'm not 100% sure that this code does not contain any critical flaws. In addition to pointing out any such oversights, I would appreciate advice on how this could be modified to make it either faster or more readable.

The functionality is supposed to be similar to the `Console.WriteLine` or `String.Format` functions of C#.

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <utility>
#include <cctype>

template <typename T>
std::string to_string(T&& item)
{
    return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(std::forward<T>(item));   
}

template <class... Args>
std::string format(const std::string& fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    std::string output;
    output.reserve(fmt.length() * 2);

    std::string arg_strings[] = { to_string(std::forward<Args>(args))... };

    bool placeholder_mode = false;
    std::string index_string;

    for (auto it = fmt.begin(); it != fmt.end(); ++it) {      
        //check for end of brace enclosed placeholder
        if ((*it == '}') && (placeholder_mode == true)) {
            if ((index_string.length() == 0)) {
                throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid format string.");
            }
            //check if index_string contains a leading zero
            if ((index_string.length() > 1) && (index_string[0] == '0')) {
                throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid format string.");
            }
            int index = std::stoi(index_string);
            if (index > (sizeof...(args) - 1)) {
                throw std::out_of_range(
                    "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal "
                    "to zero and less than the size of the argument list."
                );
            }
            output += arg_strings[index];
            index_string.clear();
            placeholder_mode = false;
            continue;
        }

        //escape double closing brace as single
        if ((*it == '}') && (*(it+1) == '}')) {
            it++;
            output.push_back('}');
            continue;
        }

        //check for unescaped closing brace
        //which doesn't close a placeholder
        if ((*it == '}') && (placeholder_mode == false)) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid format string.");
        }

        //escape double opening brace as single
        if ((*it == '{') && (*(it+1) == '{')) {
            it++;
            output.push_back('{');
            continue;
        }

        //check for begining of brace enclosed placeholder
        if ((*it == '{') && (placeholder_mode == false)) {
            placeholder_mode = true;
            continue;
        }

        if(placeholder_mode == true) {
            //check for non-digit characters
            if (isdigit(*it) == false) {
                throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid format string.");
            }
            index_string.push_back(*it);
        }
        else {
            output.push_back(*it);
        }
    }

    if (placeholder_mode == true) {
        //catch any other placeholders that were left open
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid format string.");
    }

    return output;
}

template <class... Args>
void print(const std::string& fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << format(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    print("Hello, {0}! The answer is {1}.\n", "World", 42);
}
```

**Update:** [Version 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56978/simple-parsing-for-string-formatting-version-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few points about this that seem open to improvement (at least to me).

1. Don't compare `bool`s to `true` or `false`, just use their value directly, so

   ```
   placeholder_mode == false
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   !placeholder_mode
   ```

   likewise:

   ```
   if(placeholder_mode == true)
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   if (placeholder_mode)
   ```
2. You have basically everything in one giant function. This makes the code more difficult to understand, analyze, etc.
3. Some of the checks don't seem to accomplish much (if anything)--preventing leading zeros, for one obvious example.
4. Like most parsers, this is basically a state machine. As in many cases, it would probably be somewhat clearer if the state machine were a little more explicit.

   I'd *probably* start with something like this:

   ```
   enum states { COPYING, START_PLACEHOLDER, READ_PLACEHOLDER, END_PLACEHOLDER, ERROR };

   states state;

   while (it != fmt.end()) {
   switch (state) { 
   case COPYING:
       if (*it == '{') state = START_PLACEHOLDER;
       else output.push_back(*it);
       break;
   case START_PLACEHOLDER:
       if (*it == '0') state = ERROR;
       else state = READ_PLACEHOLDER;
       // intentional fall-through
   case READ_PLACEHOLDER: 
           num = std::stoi(it);
           check_range(num, 0, arg_count);
           output.push_back(args[num]);
   ```

   ...and so on. This structure can help clarify what happens in what states, and the conditions under which you progress from one state to another.

Comment: I cannot stress enough how inexperienced I am with parsing and finite state machines. I've updated my question with my attempt to implement one, but it does not quite work correctly.