# Simple parsing for string formatting (version 2)

Tags: c++, c++11, formatting, boost, state-machine

This is my second attempt ([version 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56900/simple-parsing-for-string-formatting)) at writing a string formatting utility which uses parsing. This time I more explicitly designed it as a finite state machine. I have very little experience with writing FSMs. As before, I'm not 100% sure that this code does not contain any critical flaws. In addition to pointing out any such oversights, I would appreciate advice on how this could be modified to make it either faster or more readable.

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>
#include <cctype>

using std::to_string;

template <class T>
std::string to_string(T&& item)
{
    return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(std::forward<T>(item));   
}

template <class... Args>
std::string format(const std::string& fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    std::string arg_strs[] = { to_string(std::forward<Args>(args))... };

    std::string output, index;
    output.reserve(fmt.length() * 2);

    enum { COPYING, OPEN_BRACE, READ_INDEX, CLOSE_BRACE } state = COPYING;

    for (const char c : fmt) 
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case COPYING:
                if (c == '{') state = OPEN_BRACE;
                else if (c == '}') state = CLOSE_BRACE;
                else output += c;
                break;

            case OPEN_BRACE:
                if (isdigit(c)) {
                    index += c;
                    state = READ_INDEX;
                }
                else if (c == '{') {
                    output += '{';
                    state = COPYING;
                }
                else goto fail;
                break;

            case READ_INDEX:
                if (isdigit(c)) index += c;
                else if (c == '}') {
                    size_t i = std::stoi(index);
                    if (i >= sizeof...(args)) {
                        throw std::out_of_range(
                            "argument index is out of range in format");
                    }
                    output += arg_strs[i];
                    index.clear();
                    state = COPYING;
                }
                else goto fail;
                break;

            case CLOSE_BRACE:
                if (c == '}') {
                    output += '}';
                    state = COPYING;
                }
                else goto fail;
                break;
        }
    }

    if (state != COPYING) goto fail;
    return output;

fail:
    throw std::invalid_argument("invalid format string");
}

template <class... Args>
void print(const std::string& fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << format(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    print("Hello, {0}! The answer is {1}.", "World", 42);
}
```

Here is a diagram of the FSM:

[image]

Now just for fun, I converted this to JavaScript with regex...

```
function format(fmt, ...args) {
    if (!fmt.match(/^(?:(?:(?:[^{}]|(?:\{\{)|(?:\}\}))+)|(?:\{[0-9]+\}))+$/)) {
        throw new Error('invalid format string.');
    }
    return fmt.replace(/((?:[^{}]|(?:\{\{)|(?:\}\}))+)|(?:\{([0-9]+)\})/g, (m, str, index) => {
        if (str) {
            return str.replace(/(?:{{)|(?:}})/g, m => m[0]);
        } else {
            if (index >= args.length) {
                throw new Error('argument index is out of range in format');
            }
            return args[index];
        }
    });
}

function print(fmt, ...args) {
    console.log(format(fmt, ...args));
}

print("Hello, {0}! The answer is {1}.", "World", 42);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CS subjects like automata are too much for this problem, thats more something you have to deal with when implementing a regular expressions engine. Here is some code in C# that I've written to replace tags in a string, its absolutely not optimal because the state is checked every iteration and each character is copied individually, but you'll get the my idea.

```
private string ReplaceTags(string text, Dictionary<string, string> tags)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder tag = new StringBuilder();

    int mode = 0;

    int len = text.Length - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
    {
        char c = text[i];

        if (mode == 0)
        {
            if (text[i] == '\\')
            {
                i++;

                if (i <= len)
                {
                    result.Append(text[i]);
                }
            }
            else if (text[i] == '[')
            {
                mode = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                result.Append(text[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (text[i] == ']')
            {
                string _tag = tag.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();

                if (tags.ContainsKey(_tag))
                {
                    result.Append(tags[_tag]);
                }

                tag.Length = 0;
                mode = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                tag.Append(text[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Poor guy's getting mixed signals for sure--he did the FSM because I advised it. We may be reaching the point of personal preferences--your code strikes me as less readable (and doesn't appear intended to solve the same problem).

Comment: @JerryCoffin - I'm advising a non-scientific approach to a non-scientific problem, I think that is a good signal. And it does solve the same problem, with the difference that this parser replaces strings instead of integers.

Comment: If you look through his code, you'll quickly realize that the problem you're dealing with is substantially simplified compared to the OP's. He's not only replacing numbers, but dealing with patterns like `{{`, `{}`, leading zeros on the numbers, etc. It strikes me as a little like saying "No reason for a compiler to use those fancy FSM things. I wrote something that parses mathematical expressions in only 100 lines, with none of that stuff."

Comment: @JerryCoffin - This parser handles escape sequences as well, remark unjustified. Remove leading zeros is not a big deal. And I'm not marking FSM as fancy, I'm implying that it is irrelevant in terms of implementation, especially for this simple problem. You could read many books describing the mathematical model of FSM and you will still not know what an implementation looks like. The length of your expression parser is meaningless.

Comment: My original implementation looked more like yours. Just lots of if/elses. I think that this new implementation is easier to read and understand, so I'm not sure what benefit there would be from not using the FSM approach.

Comment: @Chris_F -- State machines are easy, fun and tempting to implement, but they have a serious disadvantage, they are slow because the state has to be checked every cycle (in this case every single character). This may be justified in the case of a complex problem such as regular expressions, but in your case I see no reason to use a state machine. I suggest a normal parser, with multiple methods to determine the rules of your format, like a recursive descent parser.

Comment: I forgot to mention, since state machines are most often encapsulated in a single method, the compiler is also less likely to apply optimizations. The parser in this post is also FSM btw, without a switch.